# Birth/Death chain

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, birth-death-process

How should I think about birth/death chains in terms of their generators?

The transition probability is obviously only nonzero when going from state $i$ to $i+1$ or $i$ to $i-1$. But how should I precisely define it? Thanks!

Comment: Could you give a reference?

Comment: It is part a of exercise: the exact phrasing is "What is the definition of a birth death chain in terms of its generator?".